# How to refactor double subscription in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I have only 1 subscribe statement in the following code using rxjs:

```
  this.authStore.jwtContainer$.subscribe(x =>
      this.userService.getUserById(x.userLoginId).subscribe(z => this.user = z));
```

I'm relatively new to rxjs, hopefully it's one of the map operators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a switchMap ( or mergeMap ) operator like following

simple way

```
this.authStore.jwtContainer$.pipe(
    switchMap(x=>this.userService.getUserById(x.userLoginId))
.subscribe(z => this.user = z);
```

better

```
this.authStore.jwtContainer$.pipe(
    map(x=>x.userLoginId),
    switchMap(loginId=>this.userService.getUserById))
.subscribe(z => this.user = z);
```

switchMap and mergeMap are made to pass result from observable to another, the simple "map" operator is here to adapt your emitted value.

Comment: Hmmm looks like I take a noticeable performance hit using switchMap here...

Comment: Why? What leads you to think so?

Comment: The difference between the two operators is simple, mergeMap will create multiple subscription each time the first observable will emit a value and then execute multiple times the second in parallel. The switchMap operator, will reuse his subscription so doesn't emit the second if another entry came early, don't know if I'm clear by here a visual example, see then replace the switchMap with mergeMap https://rxviz.com/v/0oqM1NWo

Comment: @Picci possibly the corporate anti virus :)  switchMap worked great this morning, thanks!